# Settings Activity Android methods cannot be referenced from a static content

Tags: java, android

I wanted to issue functions to my CheckBoxPreference on my Settings Activity, but I  cannot understand why I cannot use functions on my app. I am trying to mute and unmute the audio of the entire app with the use of CheckBoxPreference.

> Settings Activity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    Preference email_send;
    boolean checkboxPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainSettingsFragment sfrag = new MainSettingsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, sfrag).commit();
    }

public static class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_m);

            //this is where you put code preferences
            Preference pref;
        pref = findPreference("sounds");
        pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                if (preference.toString().equals("true")) {
                    mute();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    unmute();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

> mute

```
private void mute() {
    //mute audio
    AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
}
```

> unmute

```
public void unmute() {
    //unmute audio
    AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
}
```

> build error

```
error: non-static method mute() cannot be referenced from a static context
error: non-static method unmute() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

> UPDATE**
>   I got rid of the error, but when checking the boxes it doesnt mute the application.

```
public static class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_m);

    final Preference sprefl
    spref = findPreference("sounds");

    spref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (spref.isEnabled()) {
                AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                return true;
            } else {
                AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Im sorry i am new

Comment: Can you post the logs ?

Comment: @Maxouille
> build error

    error: non-static method mute() cannot be referenced from a static context
    error: non-static method unmute() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: In which class are these methods ?

Comment: @Maxouille they are in SettingsActivity.java

Comment: Try to remove the keyword `static` on `MainSettingsFragment `

Comment: remove `static` keyword and fix the code properly. whatever demands `Context` can only run in a `static` context, while it is possibly to pass the `Context` into the constructor/method, else not.

Comment: It says the Fragment Inner class should be static @Maxouille

Comment: Why do you need a inner class for a fragment ? You can just use the `PreferenceActivity` and no more problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused. Can you give me an example?